# Accidental VBscript fork bomb/infinite loop

Tags: vbscript

This is the first VBscript I've ever written, so I could definitely use some guidance.

Through research and snippet browsing, I've generated the following vbscript to launch a batch file.

```
dim shell
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run "permissions.bat"
set shell=nothing
WScript.Quit
```

The contents of permissions.bat are:

```
icacls "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\programFolder\mySoftwarePackage" /grant "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users":(OI)(CI)M /t
PAUSE
```

The problem I am having is that when I launch the vbscript, it never stops launching my bat file. It continuously launches instances just like a fork bomb and eventually crashes the windows kernel. Does anybody know what I did wrong here? I didn't put a while loop anywhere.

Comment: Remove the `PAUSE` in the batch file.

Comment: `pause` prevents the batch script from terminating, but I fail to see anything that might cause a fork-bomb effect or crash the system.

Comment: I removed the PAUSE in the batch file and it helps a little bit becuase the batch file closes, but as soon as it closes, the script launches a new instance so it almost looks like a strobe light of cmd windows.